# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, use-effect

I am Facing the Below Mentioned Error When Fetching Data from Firebase and Setting it to State Inside a `useEffect` Hook.

Here is The Code i am Using With Simplified Markup:

```
function PostComponent({ id }){
  const [post,setPost] = useState({});
  const [error,setError] = useState("");

  const db = firebase.firestore();

  useEffect(()=>{
    db.collection('posts').doc(id).get().then(doc=>{
      setPost(doc.data());
    }).catch(err=>setError(err.message));
  }, []);

  return (
    {error && <h1>{ error }</h1>}
    <PostCard data={post} />
  );
}
```

### Update!!

- I Fixed The Error Because i realised that it was an issue with Setting the state inside the child component.Thanks to everybody that invested time into Helping Me.

Comment: Are you sure this is the component that is causing the error?

Comment: In your `useEffect()` you are not listing the actual dependencies (`useEffect(() => { ... }, [id, setPost, setError])`)

Comment: There's no reason to define `db` outside of `useEffect`. The way the code is now, `firebase.firestore()` is executed on every render.

Comment: I have tried Every Solution Listed on This Thread But it does not work.I tried the code by commenting out the ```setPost(doc.data())``` Then it Works but now i can't Load the posts.Since i said that this is simplified `jsx` I am passing the post as props to multiple components.

Comment: Thanks For your Time and Help i Fixed The Error by Changing a few lines of code in my child Component

Answer (score 2):

Can you pls try it like this:

```js
//this can be outsite of your component
const db = firebase.firestore();

function PostComponent({ id }){
  const [post,setPost] = useState({});
  const [error,setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(()=>{
    db.collection('posts').doc(id).get().then(doc=>{
      setPost(doc.data());
    }).catch(err=>setError(err.message));
  }, [id]);

  return (
    {error && <h1>{ error }</h1>}
    <PostCard data={post} />
  );
}
```

If that doesn't work then the error is probably comming from another component.

Comment: I have tried this but the error still persists

Comment: i have came to a conclusion that setting the state inside `useEffect` is causing the infinite render loop although i have done this in other components and it works fine.

Comment: The only thing that can cause that component to rerender is the change of the `id` and the `setPost`. But when you call `setPost` it won't recall the `useEffect` to end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help as mentioned above I decided to rewrite the components to get rid of this error